# Unable to Get the Column Information when Adding a FunctionImport in ModelBrowser

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, ado.net

I am unable to get the column information from the function import in Model Browser even though I could see the results in SQL Server Management Studio. I added StoredProcedure to the StoredProcedures section in Model Browser and when I am adding the function import, I am hitting the GetColumnInformation, I am getting this "The selected stored procedure does not return no columns". But I am executing the stored procedure I could see the results.
My project is a ASP.NET MVC2 one. I am using ADO.NET Entity Model.

This is the stored proc I created

USE [MyDatabase Name]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[My Stored Proc Name] 
    @startDate datetime,
    @endDate datetime,
    @accountId int,
    @healthPlanId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @variableId as int; 
CREATE TABLE #TempAuditEvent(
    [AuditEvent_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TableId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Original_record] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [Current_record] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [ActionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OccuredOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [TriggeredBy] varchar NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [DateTime_Added] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Added_By] varchar NOT NULL,
    [DateTime_Updated] [datetime] NULL,
    [Updated_By] varchar NULL,
);
DECLARE variable_cursor CURSOR FOR
 select distinct bao.ba_Object_id from ProductInfo p 
                    join baSelection bas on p.Product_Id= bas.ba_BLID
                    join baObject bao on bas.ba_variable_Id=bao.ba_Object_id
                    where (bao.ba_Object_Type_Id = 4 or bao.ba_Object_Type_Id = 6 or bao.ba_Object_Type_Id = 22) 
                    and p.AccountId = @accountId and p.IsProduct = 1 
                    and bas.Health_Plan_ID = @healthPlanId;
OPEN variable_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM variable_cursor 
INTO @variableId;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #TempAuditEvent
 SELECT * FROM AuditEvent WHERE AuditEvent_Id in 
(
    (SELECT ae.AuditEvent_Id FROM vwProductChangesReport ae
    WHERE ae.DateTime_Added >=@startDate  AND ae.DateTime_Updated < @endDate
    AND ((ae.TableId >=12 AND ae.TableId<=14) OR ae.TableId=9 OR ae.TableId=40 OR ae.TableId=50 OR ae.TableId=64 OR ae.TableId=65)
    AND (ae.strCurrent LIKE '%Variable_Id="'+ CAST(@variableId AS varchar(20)) + '"%'
          OR ae.strCurrent LIKE '%VariableId="'+ CAST(@variableId AS varchar(20)) + '"%'
          OR ae.strCurrent LIKE '%BaObjectId="'+ CAST(@variableId AS varchar(20)) + '"%'
          OR ae.strCurrent LIKE '%ParentBaObjectId="'+ CAST(@variableId AS varchar(20)) + '"%'
          OR ae.strCurrent LIKE '%ObnId="'+ CAST(@variableId AS varchar(20)) + '"%'
          OR ae.strCurrent LIKE '%Benefit_Variable_Id="'+ CAST(@variableId AS varchar(20)) + '"%'
    ))

)
FETCH NEXT FROM variable_cursor 
    INTO @variableId;
END
CLOSE variable_cursor;
DEALLOCATE variable_cursor;

SELECT * FROM #TempAuditEvent;
DROP TABLE #TempAuditEvent;

END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem by adding 
SET FMTONLY OFF to my stored proc. It works great.